# Find shadow mapping for object

Tags: c, math, 3d, vector-graphics, glkit

So I have a light source, and a plane of sorts. Like this:

```
    |
    |
    |
o   |
    |
    |
    |
```

Plane is represented by `|`, and the light source is `o`

Now I am able to find the direction vector (is that the right term?) by subtracting the top left corner of the plane by the position of the light, like so:

```
vec3 dir = plane_top_left - light_pos
```

However, I want to be able to project the direction vector onto a farther plane, like so:

```
        | /___  I want to know where this is
       /| \
      / |
     /  |
    /   |
   /|   |
  / |   |
 /  |   |
o   |   |
    |   |
    |   |
    |   |
```

How do I know where the direction vector and the plane intersect? By the way, this is a top-down view of a 3D scene

I have looked this up on google, and became extremely confused.... answers were conflicting, and I can barely understand the math behind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with `C` specifically...

Here's what I can offer with my knowledge of space geometry: As you have said, the non-unit direction vector would be obtained by subtracting the coordinates of the initial point from the target point. Let's denote the top-left corner of your plane with `TLC` and the light source with `LS`. The non-unit direction vector would then be:

```
( TLC - LS )
```

In a three-dimensional system, this would be equivalent to:

```
< TLC_X - LS_X,
  TLC_Y - LS_Y,
  TLC_Z - LS_Z >
```

The answer for your question depends on how far the plane you want to project the light is. If it is `7/3` times as far as the original plane as in your diagram, then you could simply multiply the direction vector with that factor, and add that to the `LS`:

```
LS + ( TLC - LS ) * 7 / 3
```

Whatever you do, you'll have to add that to `LS` since it is the point of origin for the light. Depending on how far the projected plane is, the factor of multiplication will change. In general, it will be:

```
LS + ( TLC - LS ) * ( how_far_the_projected_plane_is / how_far_the_original_plane_is )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a ray-plane intersection.
If the ray is defined as following (in parametric form):

```
r = v*t + o
```

v is your dir vector (usually normalized), o is the ray origin, t - parameter.
And the target (your shadow receiving) plane is:

```
n*r + d = 0
```

n is normal vector to the plane.
From this to equations you can find t-parameter:

```
t = -(n*o + d) / (n*v)
```

And as you know t now, from the first equation you will find the intersection point r.

Note: negative t means you are not facing the plane.